# Why SOME/IP-TP required?

Tags: networking, vsomeip

If the message size is larger than the MTU, I know that fragmentation occurs in the IP layer. Why still need SOME/IP-TP?

I couldn't find the reason why SOME/IP-TP is needed even in AUTOSAR Spec.

Answer (score 1):

The Segmentation occurs in the TCP/UDP layer.
TCP supports segmentation but UDP doesn't.
According to SOME/IP spec, you should use SOME/IP over TCP if very large chunks of data need to be transported and no hard latency is required.

If you need hard latency required then there is SOME/IP-TP

> 4.2.1.4
> Transporting large SOME/IP messages of UDP (SOME/IP-TP)
> The UDP binding of SOME/IP can only transport SOME/IP messages that fit directly
> into an IP packet. If larger SOME/IP messages need to be transported over UDP
> (e.g. of 32 KB) the SOME/IP Transport Protocol (SOME/IP-TP) shall be used. The
> SOME/IP message too big to be transported directly with the UDP binding shall be
> called "original" SOME/IP message. The "pieces" of the original SOME/IP message
> payload transported in SOME/IP-TP messages shall be called "segments".
> Use TCP only if very large chunks of data need to be transported (> 1400 Bytes) and
> no hard latency requirements in the case of errors exists